# How to generate a monster with levels in wizard?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, wizard

I read in a Pathfinder book about a monster ([intellect devourer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/intellect-devourer)) that had nine levels in Wizard. How would I be able to create an NPC character sheet for such a thing? The monster without any wizard levels already has a CR 8. What are the correct steps to give it the intended levels of Wizard?

In case you want to know which book:

> Paizo's "Magnimar, City of Monuments", page 47, text passage "Kaleb has been dead for more than 5 years, his body used since then by an intellect devourer named Tiluatchek (CE intellect devourer wizard 9)"

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-to-make-monsters-with-class-levels?rq=1  but since 3.5 and PF handle parts of that differently (and the other question seems to be asking about PCs, not NPCs), I'll go ahead and answer...

Comment: While the answers are great, I would like to add some extra info, not sure if warrants an answer in itself: Wizard levels (well, spellcasting classes in general) do not stack with the Intellect devourer's existing Hit Dice, or add to it's caster level for racial abilities. This means that the final CR rating you end up with will likely be highly inappropriate for the challenge the monster actually represents. This is a RAW-tagged question, so I won't go into fixing this, as it's a good place for GM bodgery.

Comment: @Dave - PF discusses that [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-advancement#TOC-Step-3:-Determine-CR), to a point.

Comment: True, but even with the adjustment the Advanced devourer is still a CR13 challenge, which is possibly a little high. I still find that the best way to measure it is to check it's abilities against the table on the Monster Creation page, just to see. http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-creation

Comment: There is an excellent tool here: http://www.dinglesgames.com/tools/NPCGenerator/pathfinder/ for generating monsters with class levels although you need to pay for levels over a certain amount and it doesn't handle archtypes etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version:  click [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-advancement), scroll past "Adding Hit Dice" to "Adding Class Levels".  This is copied basically word-for-word from a Pathfinder book, can't recall which of core/bestiary/gamemastery guide this is from off the top of my head, will look it up when I get home from work.

Full version:  The monster's stats change when it gains it's first PC class level.  Apply a +4, +4, +2, +2, +0, and –2 to its 6 stats to change it from "average" to "heroic".  Then add the class levels like you would for any PC.  Remember that it doesn't get full hp from it's first class Hit Die.  It still gets a feat at every odd Hit Die and a +1 to a stat at every Hit Die evenly divisible by four.  Feel free to rearrange some of the feats it gained from its monstrous Hit Dice, as well, the ones in the Bestiary are for common, non-classed members of its race.  The creature's CR increases by 1 for each level you add that compliments its role, or by 1 for every two less-complimentary levels (for your example creature, these are probably counting fully).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the CR issue (although I'm not sure that in this case they class levels will count fully, but that's open to DM's judgment anyway...)

Comment: Note that 1 HD humanoids *replace* their racial HD with their first class level, unlike most creatures.

Answer (score 5):

The [Pathfinder SRD has a great page on how you advance monsters.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-advancement) In this case, you want to use the second option listed (adding class levels). It's actually very similar to adding a class level to a PC, with a couple of big exceptions.

When you add a first class level to a monster, this happens:

> The first step of this process is to modify the creature's ability
>   scores. Creatures with class levels receive +4, +4, +2, +2, +0, and –2
>   adjustments to their ability scores, assigned in a manner that
>   enhances their class abilities. Creatures with NPC class levels do not
>   receive adjustments to their ability scores.

Next, do the usual level advancement:

> Next, add the class levels to the monster, making all of the necessary
>   additions to its HD, hit points, BAB, CMB, CMD, feats, skills, spells,
>   and class features. If the creature possesses class features (such as
>   spellcasting or sneak attack) for the class that is being added, these
>   abilities stack. This functions just like adding class levels to a
>   character without racial Hit Dice.

Next, recalculate the CR and treasure. There's a table for this at the link I gave, it's somewhat large to quote here.

Note that if your first HD is from an NPC class or a monster racial HD, you do *not* gain max HP from it like a PC would at level 1. If the first HD is from a PC appropriate class, the creature does gain max HP. So something with monster stats where you add a PC class on top does not get max HP from that class HD (calculate it normally).