# d&d 3.5 can anyone help understand how to make a monster race as a playable race?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, skills

First of all, Hello.

I am very very very very new to D&D.

### I want to create a character from a monster race. I have read the books but I can't understand them. I will use Drow elf as an example

the questions are:

1)what is the level adjustment and how do I use it?

2)what are those?

[image]

3)how to add the proper level adjustment to a race that I have created?

---

Well I hope it doesn't sound complicated. Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you clean up this question to be a single question? It's very hard to tell what *specific* problem you're having here. Start by articulating your specific intention and what work you've completed so far.

Comment: When you say "race you have created" do you mean "apply the drow level adjustment to a character?"

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Pretty sure, being new to *D&D*, the latter is meant but the language isn't there yet. This nonetheless appears answerable in its current form. (Although I dread explaining *D&D 3.5*'s mad concoction of character levels, Hit Dice, LA, and ECL to a newcomer.)

Comment: This should really be closed as "too broad". The very first reason fits perfectly: *"if your question could be answered by an entire book"*. There's even more than one. As a new player, asking for monster characters is like asking for definite integrals when you just attended a class for multiplication and addition of numbers below 10. You cannot even *understand* this "whole books" without the foundation.

Comment: I feel like the first two questions are definitely answerable (the third is someting I would not ask as a new player, and it's very broad and requires a detailed dissertation on how the currently existing LAs were assigned, which also makes it opinion based. I think that's better suited to our chat). An answer to the 1st question is already [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28176/how-exactly-does-a-level-adjustment-work) and [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-to-make-monsters-with-class-levels?rq=1) so it'd be a duplicate. The 2nd question seems to be ok.

Comment: VTCing until which sub-question this is about is sorted out. Otherwise, answers to one or some of these questions might be wasted once it's fixed.

Comment: What does the OP not understand exactly? Level Adjustment? That is pretty cut and dry.

Comment: @Ruut this has already been explained in the questions I linked in a previous comment (where I also explain which are the multiple closing reasons). I'd edit the question to have only question number 2 here but I fear the querent could lose track of where to find the replies to his ither questions.